# Array Modifier Object Offset acting odd

Tags: modifiers

I'm pretty new to Blender so I apologize is this is a silly issue or has been answered before..

I'm trying to make a wagon wheel, but whenever I add the array modifier and apply 'Object Offset', in my case to an empty, the array pieces sort of.. hover around the empty in a weird way. They all vary in sizes and are stretched oddly..

[image: Array]

I have Rotation and Scale lock applied to the original piece and all centers are lined up... Even doing exactly what a demonstration video does I get this weird result.. Not sure why it's happening.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome! ^^ Could you share your Blend file so we can take a look?

Comment: Here you are! 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zs397qgyovko0u/array%20wheel.blend?dl=0

Sorry if there is another to upload >.< I hope this works.